# ExcelRichTextHtmlUtility is missing from nuget package

Tags: epplus

ExcelRichTextHtmlUtility does not appear in the EPPlus 4.5.1 library (or 4.1 for that matter).  I see it's in the code in source control but doesn't get shipped I guess.  Is there a particular reason or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the source code but not compiled as part of the project anymore. When I include [ExcelRichTextHtmlUtility.cs](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/v4.5.1/EPPlus/Style/ExcelRichTextHtmlUtility.cs), the following line does not compile:

```
s = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
```

In taking a look at the [project settings](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/v4.5.1/EPPlus/EPPlus.csproj), EPPlus targets the .NET 3.5 Client Profile framework. The Client Profile is a subset of the framework which for example does not include `System.Web`, so `HttpUtility` cannot be used so they must have just simply excluded the class.

I couldn't find any reference to exactly when and why this was changed so this probably does not completely answer your question.